# In sqoop export, Avro table to define schema in RDBMS

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, sqoop, avro

I'm loading data from HDFS to mySQL using SQOOP, in this data one record has got more than 70 fields, making it difficult to define the schema while creating the table in RDBMS.

Is there a way to use AVRO tables to dynamically create the table with schema in RDBMS using SQOOP?

Or is there any some tool which does the same?

Comment: Sqoop doesn't have that capability, Maybe some other tool can do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in sqoop today. From the sqoop documentation

> The export tool exports a set of files from HDFS back to an RDBMS. The
>   target table must already exist in the database. The input files are
>   read and parsed into a set of records according to the user-specified
>   delimiters.

Comment: I understand that this is supported in sqoop, but is there some other tool which does the job?